# matplotlib annotations vertical line annotations

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization

I found the following code in the Python for Data Science Handbook (Thank You for creating such a comprehensive book on this topic).

`ax.annotate('', xy=('2012-9-1', 4850), xytext=('2012-9-7', 4850),
            xycoords='data', textcoords='data',
            arrowprops={'arrowstyle': '|-|,widthA=0.2,widthB=0.2', })`

This annotation put a bar on this line graph.  I am looking for a similar arrowstyle, but vertical.  [image]

Here is my code, and the image I have produced.  I want to put a similar arrowstyle showing the distance between two points (I marked my desired line with snipit).  Any thoughts on the best way to annotate to show the difference between these two points?

```
df_low_high.sort_values('Number_High_Ratings', inplace = True)
figure, axes = plt.subplots()
axes.plot(df_low_high.index,df_low_high['Number_High_Ratings'], color = 'goldenrod')
axes.plot(df_low_high.index,df_low_high['Number_Low_Ratings'], color = 'mediumseagreen')
axes.legend()
axes.set_title('High and Low Rated')
axes.annotate(
    'Lowest Number of Low Ratings', 
    xy=(2.2, 150), xytext=(3,150), size=8,
    bbox=dict(boxstyle="round", fc="none", ec="gray"),
    arrowprops=dict(
        width=3, 
        headwidth=10, 
        headlength=10
    )  
)
```

[image]

Reference to O'Reilly publication.
https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/python-data-science/9781491912126/ch04.html

Comment: What's the problem you encounter? Did you try to create this annotation?

Comment: I triedd a variety text following `'arrowstyle':`, but was really just shooting in the dark, as I couldn't find documentation on the different arrowstyles available.

Comment: You already have the code written in the question. All you need to do is use your coordinates instead of the ones the example uses.

Comment: Hmm...ok, I guess i am doing something else incorrectly, because I am unable to reproduce the arrow style.  All the other arrow styles that i have used (traditional, with a head and a tail) do not follow the same syntax as this one `'arrowstyle': '|-|,widthA=0.2,widthB=0.2'` , so i am just not sure why this type of an arrow style is different than 'fancy' or 'wedge'.

Comment: That's a different question, right? Once it works you can still question why it works.

Comment: For anyone interested, here is the code that i was able to get working.

`axes.annotate('', xy=(2, 130), xytext=(2, 820),
            arrowprops={'arrowstyle': '<|-|>,head_length=0.4,head_width=0.2', })`

I think my biggest problem was getting the starting and endpoints to show up.  It is intuitive now that I see it in a completed form, but plotting the arrow wasn't intuitive the first time.